# How i can add code in server control attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this code `<asp:Label Text="<%=Test()%>" runat="server"></asp:Label>`
<%=Test()%> does not work. How i can run code on server control with `runat="server"`?

Comment: I imagine a more standard (and more expected by other developers supporting this code) approach would be to assign an `ID` to the `Label` and set it in code-behind, probably in `Page_Load`: `someLabel.Text = Test();`  Is there a particular reason *not* to do that?

Comment: @FelipeOriani    public string Test()
       {
           return "Test";
       }

Answer (score 0):

As @david said:

Just move your `Text="<%=Test()%>"` assignment in the code behind.

Probably the best place in your code behind is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        yourLabelId.Text = Test();
    }
}
```